# Securing a REST API consumed from Ajax and mobile apps and 3rd party developers

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, security

I have am writing a REST API (using ASP.NET WebApi) and it will be used by my single page web app via client side JavaScript calls mobile apps that anyone can install and eventually I would like it to be used by thirst party developers to write their own apps.

I have looked into HMAC to secure the API but not sure how to get the private key onto the clients securely (I.e. browser client side, on mobile app?

I am trying to make it so only my apps, the 3rd party dev apps and my client side JavaScript can access the api.

Answer (score 1):

In your use case, I would use two different authentication mechanisms. For the SPA running in the browser, I would authenticate the users using forms authentication, and I would rely on ASP.NET to validate the credentials stored in the cookie when the browser makes a call to the Web API using AJAX. For the third party or mobile apps, I would use HMAC authentication. You can exchange that key out of band as many of the cloud providers like Windows Azure or AWS do. I created an implementation of HMAC for Web API that you can use. It's available here, 
https://github.com/pcibraro/hawknet

You can also exchange the key using SSL on the first call when the user is authenticated with username and password, but that's up to you.

Regards
Pablo

Comment: Thanks for that not sure about forms and cookie, would prefer something more restful and also would like it to be the same across all devices.